# Counter-example to passing limit under integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I currently want to show the following statement is not true without the condition $\left\{f_n\right\}$'s are non-negative functions:

"Given the set $E$ of finite measure. Suppose the sequence of integrable functions $\left\{f_n\right\}$ that converges pointwise almost everywhere on $E$ to $\ f=0$. We then have: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{E} \ f_n = 0$ **IFF** $\ \left\{f_n\right\}$ is uniformly integrable over $E$."

**My attempt:** For several hours, I tried to use contradiction method by assuming the statement above is still correct even when ${f_n}$'s are negative. But I could not see why the theorem failed, except that the proposition used in the proof for the theorem above cannot be applied for the case when  ${f_n}$'s are negative. Can someone please help with this problem?

Comment: The opposite of a non-negative function is not a negative function, but a function that takes at least one negative value. If $f_n$ is negative then $g_n=-f_n$ is positive. So the theorem applies to $g_n$ and in this case, also for $f_n$.  But when $f_n$ can take both negative and positive values,  the theorem does not hold. Good answer by RRI.

Comment: @user254665: Thanks for pointing that mistake to me. I was so dumb:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  $f_n(x) = n\chi_{[0,1/n]} - n\chi_{[1-1/n,1]}$ over $E = [0,1].$

We have $f_n \to 0$ a.e. and $\int_E f_n = 0 \to 0$. However, $\{f_n\}$ is not uniformly integrable, which is shown as follows:

Choose $\epsilon = 1/4$. If $A_n = [0,1/2n] \subset E$ then $m(A_n) < 1/n$ but $\int_{A _n}|f_n| = 1/2 > \epsilon$ even as $m(A_n) \to 0$.

Clearly $f_n$ must be non-negative for the statement to be true.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, I just wonder if this is the correct argument for why $f_n\rightarrow 0$ a.e: From the definition of $f_n$, as $n\rightarrow 0$, the two sets $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and $[1-\frac{1}{n},1]$ have measures $0$. Thus, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, the measure of the COMPLEMENT of these two sets $= m(0,1) = 1$, and $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow 0$ on this complement set, so we conclude that $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere?

Comment: You are making an argument for convergence in measure.  Just make a simple direct argument for a.e. convergence.  For any fixed $x \in (0,1)$ eventually when n gets large you have $1/n < x < 1- 1/n$  and $f_n(x) = 0$.  Hence we have pointwise convergence to $0$ except on the zero measure set containing the end points $x \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I found your proof quite similar to mine related to the a.e convergence. Basically, I showed that as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $f_n(x)\rightarrow 0$ pointwise on a set of measure $1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and it cannot converge to $0$ on a complement set, which is a set of measure $0$. Why is this argument flawed?

Comment: If $m(\{x:|f_n(x)| > \epsilon\}) \to 0$ for all $\epsilon >0$ then we say $f_n \to 0$ in measure. This only guarantees that $f_n$ has an a.e. convergent subsequence.  You make a stronger statement,  $m(\{x:|f_n(x)| > 0) \to 0$ which you are asserting implies $f_n \to 0$ a.e. without proving it.  Perhaps this always holds -- I would need to look at it.  As I show above, a.e. convergence is really quite easily demonstrated directly.

Comment: Here is the almost everywhere convergence definition: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/modes_of_convergence/. My proof just followed the definition. Your proof is equivalent to mine I think?

Comment: I think you are correct.  At first I mistakenly thought you were trying prove convergence in measure but you showed $m(\{x: |f_n(x)| > 0\} \to 0$ which is stronger.  It must imply a.e convergence. Good effort.